# How can I construct a new File in the bowser from reading a file in Nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I am using puppeteer to run some automated tests. One of the test includes uploading a file. How can I read a file in Nodejs and generate a new File in the browser. I feel like I'm close, but I can't seem to get the data into the right type.

Here is what I'm attempting.

I'm using this simple package as well: [cross-blob](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-blob)

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const fs = require('fs');
const Blob = require("cross-blob");

const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto('testwebsite.com');

const dropzone = await page.$('#dropzone');
const fileData = fs.readFileSync('test.jpg');
const blob = new Blob(fileData);
console.log(blob); // <-- Logging out blog looks good to me. 

await page.waitFor(1000);

try {
  await page.evaluate((blob) => {
    const file = new File([blob], 'test.jpg');

    var fakeDropEvent = new DragEvent('drop');

    var dT = new DataTransfer();
    dT.items.add(file);

    Object.defineProperty(fakeDropEvent, 'dataTransfer', {
      value: dT
    });

    window.dispatchEvent(fakeDropEvent);
  }, blob);

} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
}
```

When I log out the File in the browser after the "drop", I see the file below:

```
0: File
name: "test.jpg"
lastModified: 1587457550129
lastModifiedDate: Tue Apr 21 2020 01:25:50 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time) {}
webkitRelativePath: ""
size: 15 // <-- This is not right. 
type: "" // <-- This is also incorrect.
```

How can I get the file blob that I created in Node into a [File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File)

Answer (score 1):

First, I ditched the cross-blob package.

The solution I came up with was to create the Blob in the browser where native functionality exists, and pass base64 encoded string to the browser.

First, I read the file to a buffer, and encode it as a base64 string which I can pass to puppeteer.

```
const filebuffer = fs.readFileSync('test.jpg');
const rawBase64 = filebuffer.toString('base64');
const base64 = `data:image/jpeg;base64,${rawBase64}`;
```

The last line is essential if you're sending to the browser because it's expecting base64 encoded string to have an identifying prefix that I concatenated above.

Next I pass that to puppeteer, and convert it to a Blob.

```
  try {

    await page.evaluate((base64) => {
      var blob = convertBase64ToBlob(base64);
      var file = new File([blob], 'test.jpg', {type: 'image/jpeg'});

      var fakeDropEvent = new DragEvent('drop');

      var dT = new DataTransfer();
      dT.dropEffect = "none";
      dT.effectAllowed = "all";
      dT.items.add(file);

      Object.defineProperty(fakeDropEvent, 'dataTransfer', {
        value: dT
      });

      window.dispatchEvent(fakeDropEvent);
      console.log("Processing Image...");

      function convertBase64ToBlob(Base64Image) {
        // Split into two parts
        const parts = Base64Image.split(';base64,');

        // Hold the content type
        const imageType = parts[0].split(':')[1];

        // Decode Base64 string
        const decodedData = window.atob(parts[1]);

        // Create UNIT8ARRAY of size same as row data length
        const uInt8Array = new Uint8Array(decodedData.length);

        // Insert all character code into uInt8Array
        for (let i = 0; i < decodedData.length; ++i) {
            uInt8Array[i] = decodedData.charCodeAt(i);
        }

        // Return BLOB image after conversion
        return new Blob([uInt8Array], { type: imageType });
      }
    }, base64); // <-- Passing value to evaluate method.
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
```